# Difference Between Script Rendering Code in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I create an MVC project that uses Razor, the following lines are generated:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

What is the difference between these lines ? Is it the case that `@Scripts.Render` generates a `<scripts>` section and then `@RenderSection("scripts", false)` renders it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one renders out a bundle, which is a group of related Javascript files. For instance, you might want to bundle jQuery and jQuery UI together. Bundles also get the benefit of bundling and minification when a solution is compiled in release mode. ref: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

`@RenderSection` indicates that a page that uses the layout in question can inject markup in a particular spot in the layout. Sections are in effect a placeholder (and work much like the `ContentPlaceHolder` server control from web forms if you are familiar with that). That reference is probably right before the closing body tag, where it is believed by some to be the best spot to put scripts. You could have a section called `scripts`, or `head`, or `footer`, it is completely arbitrary and sections don't necessarily have anything to do with scripts at all. ref: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor

Answer (score 5):

These are completely different things.

The `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` is rendering a group of scripts for you, creating all the `<script>` tags. in the `BundleConfig.cs` file you are able to create bundles of scripts and css files.
One of its advantages allow you to group multiple files that are commonly used together. Instead of including each of these files explicitly you can include all of them using explicit `Scripts.Render(groupName)`. 
You can read more about [**Bundling and Minification** here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

The `@RenderSection("scripts", false)` is about rendering a section in the view.
A section allow you to specify a region of content within a layout. It expects one parameter which is the name of the section. If you don’t provide that, an exception will be thrown.
Here is a good article explaining about [**Layouts, RenderBody, RenderSection and RenderPage in ASP.NET MVC**](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/9Ya6290314-Layouts,-RenderBody,-RenderSection-and-RenderPage-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html).

> The first parameter to the “RenderSection()” helper method specifies
>   the name of the section we want to render at that location in the
>   layout template.  The second parameter is optional, and allows us to
>   define whether the section we are rendering is required or not.  If a
>   section is “required”, then Razor will throw an error at runtime if
>   that section is not implemented within a view template that is based
>   on the layout file (which can make it easier to track down content
>   errors).  If a section is not required, then its presence within a
>   view template is optional, and the above RenderSection() code will
>   render nothing at runtime if it isn’t defined.